# Spring boot JPA specification executor between function

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to compare a date in my db between 2 days. I tried it as,

```
ZonedDateTime startBottomTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 9, 10, 15, 55, 33, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime startTopTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 9, 13, 15, 55, 35, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);

predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDatetime"), startBottomTime));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDatetime"), startTopTime));
```

This returns me 0 results. But I executed the following query, works fine and gave me the expected result.

```
SELECT * from file_data fd where fd.created_date_time between '2020-09-10 15:55:33' AND '2020-09-13 15:55:35'
```

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following using java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
[...]

Date startDate = c.getTime();

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);
[...]

Date endDate = c.getTime();

//between is not the same as greater than equal and less than or equal, exclude the limits
predicates.add(cb.between(root.get("createdDatetime"), startDate, endDate));
```